# ReferenceError - Function not defined when using onchange attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the value of an input based on what was selected on a dropdown menu, but it always returns "undefined". Here is the HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown">
   <option id="AU">Australia</option>
   <option id="CH" >Switzerland</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="regionInput">
```

And the JS:

```
document.getElementById('dropdown').setAttribute("onchange","myFunction()");

function myFunction(){

 var country = document.getElementById('dropdown').options[document.getElementById('dropdown').selectedIndex].text;
 var region = document.getElementById('regionInput').value;

 if (country == "Australia"){
  region = 'test';
   } else {
    region = 'test 2';
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Is `myFunction()` defined in the global scope? Code in inline event handler attributes is run in the global scope, it can't access nested functions and variables.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're defining the function a local scope of another function. Code called from `onXXX` attributes is executed in the global scope.

You can use `addEventListener` and provide a function reference:

```
document.getElementById('dropdown').addEventListener("change",myFunction);
```

Notice that the event name doesn't begin with `on`, and you don't put `()` after the function name (that will call the function instead of passing a reference).

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the quotation mark `""` in myFuction() like this: `document.getElementById('dropdown').setAttribute("onchange", myFunction() );`

Comment: The value of an attribute has to be a string.

Comment: You're also calling the function immediately, rather than passing a reference to the function.